# Vue.js disabling other js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have made a dependent dropdown with vue.js and integrated 2 other jquery app for multi-select (select2 and multi-select). The trouble I'm having is other two plugins don't run when vue js is enabled [add element to `el:`], when vue element is removed both plugin runs smoothly. Code snipped.

[Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/bantawa04/2manp88k/1/)

Comment: The JSFiddle you posted seems to be working for me.What is actual problem ?

Comment: It is not working in my Laravel  project. Both dropdowns are disabled as plugins are wrapped inside el:#app. If I remove el:#app it works.

Comment: What I can suggest you is to init jQuery things into the `mounted()` hook - https://jsfiddle.net/7zLzgh0o/ 
Also make sure you have jQuery imported - something like this `import $ from 'jquery'`.

Comment: Well i did this `jQuery(function($){
 "use strict";

var EASY = window.EASY || {};

EASY.Country = function(){
  $('.select2-multi').select2();
}
 
EASY.Included = function(){
    $("#included").multipleSelect({
        placeholder: "What's included ?"
    });
} 
$(document).ready(function(){
 EASY.Country ();
 EASY.Included (); 
});

});
` `EASY.Country` works but `EASY.Included` doesn't.

Comment: Screw this, I went for plain js :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you have use `v-if` directive; it injects the html or the component when the condition is met. Use `v-show` it just inline the css "`display:none`" to "`display:block`"

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

As you have used `v-if`, the element is not render on dom. Its not available for the jquery selector to select that element
Here is the working example

https://jsfiddle.net/gowdagold/2manp88k/7/

```
var region = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data: {
      first_value: '',
    },
    mounted() {
          
    },
    computed: {
      show() {
        console.log(this.first_value)
          if ('1' === this.first_value) {
            return true;
          } else
            return false;
          },
       hide() {
         console.log(this.first_value)
           if ('2' === this.first_value) {
             return true;
           } else
             return false;
           }
       }
    }
  });
$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use other plugins inside of VueJS component:

```
mounted: function() {
  $(this.$el).datepicker();
}
```